# possible to write product custom attributes into session?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, session

I have a product custom attribute, want to write in session when then product detail page was load. So I can get use the session value on the other block on the same page. Anyone can give me an advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom value in registry instead. On product detail page, the product object is already present in the registry.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_registry;
 
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 */

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

/**
 * Set custom variable in registry
 *
 */
public function setCustomVariable()
{
    $this->registry->register('custom_variable', 'Test Value');
}
 
/**
 * Get custom variable from registry
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomVariable()
{
     return $this->registry->registry('custom_variable');
}

/**
 * Return catalog product object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}
```